# assignment to multiple indirectly addressed variables

Tags: python

Single assignment works like this: (there may be better ways)

```
b='bb'
vars()[b] = 10
bb
>>>10
```

but if I do this:

```
c='cc'
vars() [b,c]= 10,11
```

it doesn't successfully assign `bb` and `cc`.

I don't understand why, nor how best to do this.

Thanks

PS, several people have asked, quite reasonably, why I wanted to do this.  I found I was setting up a lot of variables and objects according to options specified by the user.  So if the user specified options 2, 3 and 7, I would want to create a2, a3 and 7, plus b2, b3, b7 etc.  It may not be usual practice but using vars and eval is a very easy and transparent way to do it, requiring simple concise code:

For i in input_vector:  vars()['a'+input_vector[i]] = create_a (input_vector[i])

For i in input_vector:  vars()['b'+input_vector[i]] = create_b (input_vector[i])

This works for some of the data.  The trouble is when I use another function, create_c_and_d.  This requires me to compress the above two lines into one function call.  If this can be done easily using dictionaries, I am happy to switch to that method.  I am new to python so it isn't obvious to me whether it can.

Comment: Why do you want to do this anyway?

Comment: [Keep data out of your variable names](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html). Luckily, the answer to *this* question is independent of whether you're fooling around with `vars()` or using ordinary dictionaries.

Comment: The docs recommend that `vars()` be treated as read-only; changes to the dictionary it returns are not guaranteed to be propagated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `b,c` is a `tuple`, so you're actually assiging to the key `('bb', 'cc')`.

```
>>> vars() [b,c]= 10,11
>>> vars()[('bb', 'cc')]
(10, 11)

>>> x = b,c
>>> type(x)
<type 'tuple'>
```

Comment: @alko Try `help(vars)`, simply use `vars()[b] = 10;vars()[c] = 11`, if you want a one line solution then use: `vars()[b], vars()[c] = 10, 11`.

Comment: thanx, didn't knew that's a builtin; should have tried then))

Answer (score 0):

> I don't understand why, nor how best to do this.

Well, I have to say, uh.. the best way would be to not do it.  At all.

Just use a `dict` like it's supposed to be used:

```
d = {}
d['aa'] = 10
d['bb'] = 11
```

Anyway, to answer your question, you're doing the `tuple` unpacking in the wrong place.  Or, rather, not unpacking at all; when you specify `a,b` to a `dict`, that means you're assigning a `tuple` as the key.  Instead, unpack like this:

```
vars()[b], vars()[c] = 10,11
```

I'll again recommend that you not do this and just use `dict`s to map strings (or whatever hashable datatype) to values.  Dynamically naming variables is not good practice.